# Adding new Local Secondary Index to an existing DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to add a new Local Secondary Index to an existing DynamoDB table?

Comment: Come on AWS give us this feature! Pretty please.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

no, you cant do it, only adding global secondary index is possible to an existing table.

from [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.Creating):

```
Local secondary indexes on a table are created when the table is created.
```

Comment: What if the design of the database changes or evolves with the same table? How do we handle that?

Comment: @kashyapjimuliya like how? do you have an example? you can always add/delete global secondary indexes

Comment: Like example, I have created two tables and for each there is LSI but when I want to add some new column to one of the tables and I want to make it as LSI for third table to have a One-to-One or One-to-Many relation. What I need to know is how is that scenario going to play out?

Comment: @kashyapjimuliya you can always add later secondary global index

Comment: but I want to use the same partition key for GSI as of table partition key. for this reason i needed LSI, since LSI is not possible, can i create GSI as such with same partition key

Comment: @EyalCh the problem with GSI is it doesn't support strong consistency. In case we really need to add a index with strong consistency, we got to go LSI, however that require us to rebuild the table is really painful. Particularly when we have already adopted the single table design as recommended by some DDB expert.